# getCellType() of Poi throws NullPointerException, when cell value is blank

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have used the following code to print all the values from an Excel spreasheet using POI. It works fine, when there is value in all the cells. However, if there is Blank cell it throws a `NullPointerException`. I observed that `getCellType()` method throws this exception. Can you please help in printing all the values, even if there is blank cell?

```
public class ExcelRead4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("D:/Batch2_Excel/ExcelRead.xlsx");
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            Sheet sht = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            int rowcount = sht.getLastRowNum();
            for (int i = 0; i <= rowcount; i++) {
                int celCount = sht.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();
                for (int j = 0; j < celCount; j++) {
                    Cell cel = sht.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                    int cel_Type = cel.getCellType();                           
                    switch(cel_Type) {
                    case 0: System.out.print(cel.getNumericCellValue()+ " ");
                            break;
                    case 1:System.out.print(cel.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                            break;
                    case 4: System.out.print(cel.getBooleanCellValue()+" ");
                            break;
                    case 3:
                            System.out.print(" "+" ");
                            break; 
                    default:
                            System.out.print("inside the default..");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to check if the cell is null, before calling any methods on it:

```
if (cel == null) {
    continue;
}
```

Replace the continue part with what you need, this way it simply ignores the cell.

Comment: Was just about to post something similar. Even if the question doesn't point out exactly where the error occurs, this must be correct, since `Cell#getCellType()` returns `Cell#CELL_TYPE_BLANK` in case of an empty cell that is not null.

Comment: The question *do say* that `#getCellType()` throws the exception

Comment: @meskobalazs Well, yes it does. I expressed myself poorly. What I think OP means is that `cel.getCellType()` throws the error. Which makes your answer correct since `cel` is `null`.

Comment: Since the getCelltype() was throwing an error , i changed the logic a bit and it worked as per your answer.

I have one more question can we directly use the following code to get read the excel value??

for(int i=0;i<=rowCount;i++)
   {
    int celCount=sht.getRow(i).getLastCellNum();
    //System.out.println(celCount);
    
    for(int j=0;j<celCount;j++)
    {
     System.out.print(sht.getRow(i).getCell(j) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
   }
   
 
   
   
  }

Comment: Here when i use System.out.print(sht.getRow(i).getCell(j)) it directly prints all the values inspite of whether excel has null values or no.

Answer (score 2):

```
int cel_Type = cel.getCellType();
```

Replace the aforementioned part of your code with the bellow one. It will work. Tested the same on my machine.

```
int cel_Type;

try {
cel_Type = cel.getCellType();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
cel_Type = 3;
}
```

Comment: Better simply check if "cel" is null. Catching an exception affects performance.